# C Dereference void* pointer

Tags: c, pointers, void, void-pointers

I am new to C and for my first project I need to implement an array based queue.

I want my queue to be able to hold any kind of object so I created a QueueElement structure to hold a void pointer to an object of any type. I think all is working except I am unable to read the 'position' and 'value' fields from my QueueElement struct. I get the following error when I try to compile.

**Error:**

```
Runnable.c: In function `main':
Runnable.c:10: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Runnable.c:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just not casting properly. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks again,
Pooch

**Runnable.c**

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include "Queue.h"
    
    int main(void) {
            int i = 9;
            Queue q = CreateQueue();
            QueueElement e = CreateQueueElement(&i);
            Enqueue(q, e);
            QueueElement f = Dequeue(q);


            /* PROBLEM IS HERE */
            printf("position: %d", f->position);
            printf("value: %d", (int *)(f->value));
            DestroyQueue(q);
            return 0;
    }
```

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include "QueueElement.h"

typedef struct QueueStruct *Queue;

Queue CreateQueue(void);

void DestroyQueue(Queue q);

void Enqueue(Queue q, QueueElement e);

QueueElement Dequeue(Queue q);

#endif
```

**Queue.c**

```
#include "QueueElement.h"
#include "Queue.h"

#define QUEUE_SIZE 10

struct QueueStruct {
        QueueElement contents[QUEUE_SIZE];
        int size;
};

Queue CreateQueue(void) {
        Queue q = malloc(sizeof(struct QueueStruct));
        q->size = 0;
        return q;
}

void DestroyQueue(Queue q) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < q->size; i++) {
                free(q->contents[i]);
        }
        free(q);
}

void Enqueue(Queue q, QueueElement e) {
        if (q->size < QUEUE_SIZE) {
                q->contents[q->size++] = e;
        }
}

QueueElement Dequeue(Queue q) {
        if (q->size > 0) {
                return q->contents[--q->size];
        }
        return;
}
```

**QueueElement.h**

```
#ifndef QUEUE_ELEMENT_H
#define QUEUE_ELEMENT_H

typedef struct QueueElementStruct *QueueElement;

QueueElement CreateQueueElement(void *v);

void DestroyQueueElement(QueueElement e);

int GetPosition(QueueElement e);

#endif
```

**QueueElement.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "QueueElement.h"

struct QueueElementStruct {
        int position;
        void *value;
};

QueueElement CreateQueueElement(void *v) {
        QueueElement e = malloc(sizeof(struct QueueElementStruct));
        e->position = 0;
        e->value = v;
        return e;
}

void DestroyQueueElement(QueueElement e) {
        free(e);
}

int GetPosition(QueueElement e) {
        return e->position;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `QueueElementStruct` has to be visible in Runnable.c to be able to access fields of it. You can put `QueueElementStruct` into a header that you can include in `Runnable.c` and `QueueElement.c`. Alternatively, you can use your `GetPosition` function and add a `GetValue` function and use those from `Runnable.c` instead of direct field access.

Comment: Runnable.c includes Queue.h which in turn includes QueueElement.h Does this linking of includes work?

Comment: It does, but QueueElement.h doesn't say define the members of QueueElementStruct, it merely suggests its existence. If I include QueueElement.h all I know is there is a struct named QueueElementStruct, not its constituents. Only QueueElement.c knows what the members of QueueElementStruct are.

Comment: Logan, I used your advice along with Jerry's and my code compiled. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast the `void *` back to point at the "real" type before you can dereference it. e.g., if you start with an `int`, you can take its address, and put it in the queue. To look at the `int`, you'll have to cast it back to `int *`. Keeping track of the real type can be (usually is) non-trivial (e.g., creating an enumeration of all types you want to be able to put in the collection and associating one of those with each item in the collection).

There's a reason that C++ (for one example) opts for only putting one type of object into any given collection.

Comment: don't I cast it back into an int on this line: printf("value: %d", (int *)(f->value));

Comment: @Pooch: Maybe -- I'm afraid I didn't trace through all 200 (or whatever) lines of code to be sure. OTOH, the bit of code in your comment clearly has a problem -- you're casting `f->value` to `int *`, but then passing it to `printf` with a `"%d"` conversion, which expects an `int`, not a pointer. Perhaps you intended something like `*(int *)(f->value)`?